# Unpack the first two elements in list/tuple

Tags: python, unpack

Is there a way in Python to do like this:

```py
a, b, = 1, 3, 4, 5
```

and then:

```py
>>> a
1
>>> b
3
```

The above code doesn't work as it will throw

> `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: In Python2? or Python3? Please tag accordingly. Assuming Python2

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Just to add to Nolen's answer, in Python 3, you can also unpack the rest, like this:

```
>>> a, b, *rest = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
>>> a
1
>>> rest
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work in Python 2 though.

Comment: Seems like nowadays nobody would ever care that it doesn't work in Python 2 :P

Answer (score 72):

There is no way to do it with the literals that you've shown.  But you can slice to get the effect you want:

```
a, b = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6][:2]
```

To get the **first two** values of a list:

```
a, b = my_list[:2]
```

Comment: +1 even though the OP said he already knew this but it seems to be edited out of the question.

Answer (score 39):

On Python 3 you can do the following:

```
>>> a, b, *_ = 1, 3, 4, 5
>>> a
1
>>> b
3
```

`_` is just a place holder for values you don't need

Answer (score 6):

You could use `_` to represent variables you wanted to "throw away"

```
>>> a, b, _ = 1, 3, 4
>>> a
1
>>> b
3
```

Comment: Thanks! but it won't work when there're more element ``a,b,_ = 1,3,4,5``

Comment: @Firegun you're right, you would have to do something like `a, b, _, _ = 1, 3, 4, 5` which gets ugly fast.  Honestly I think just getting a list and using `[:2]` makes more sense and is more pythonic.

Comment: This method works well if it is not an explicit slice you are getting, eg `(x,_,z,h) = coord` instead of `(x,z,h) = coord[:1]+coord[2:]`. For larger tuples, you end up with stuff like `(_,_,c,_,e,f,_) = something`, which is arguably better than having a mess of index accesses.

Answer (score 4):

Or in Python 3.x you could do this:

```
  a, *b = 1, 3, 4
```

giving you:

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: b
Out[16]: [3, 4]
```

It would avoid the exception, though you would have to parse `b`. This assume that you only want to have two variables on the left of the `=`, otherwise you could use

```
a, b, *ignore = ....
```

with v3.x